# Highlighting Gridview with Color

Tags: c#, gridview, highlight

I have a Gridview in which some Bill details will appear the user have to click on a button in the Gridview in order to submit it, I need to Highlight (change the Color) of the Gridview when the User clicks on the Button in the Gridview.
I have tried with the `Gridview_RowDataBound()` but it's not working.
How can I achive this of Highlighting the Gridview.

The Code I tried is,

```
 protected void gvStuSel_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Blue");
 }
```

Comment: Can you show me `Gridview_RowDataBound()`'s code ?

Comment: @ Zey I had edited my Question with the Code but It is not a big code its just one line code

Comment: What about using `System.Drawing.Color.Blue`  ?

Comment: @bummi , can you pls help.. I have a grid view with image as a single item in grid When I m clicking in space left around image ,I get touch feedback from gridview but no feedback on clicking on the image.. what can I do? thanks.